# How to hide facebook customer chat plugin on specific pages of my SPA?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, nuxt.js, facebook-chat

We have SPA (single page application, generated nuxtjs project) with facebook customer chat plugin on it.

This plugin is initialized during page refresh and remains on the site after router loads view.

We want to show this plugin only on specific pages such as landing page, support page, payment page and hide on the rest pages.

During initial load the plugin creates iframe with all the magic inside it and this iframe remains during SPA navigation untouched.

The question is - how to properly hide facebook customer chat plugin on specific pages? Destroy iframe? Some undocumented settings? Another magic?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just hiding the `.fb-customerchat` element? Usually these Facebook social plugins render _inside_ of the element that was used to embed them, the iframe should be inserted as a descendant of that.

Comment: Finally I did like this. I set display:none on this element on the pages where chat plugin is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Аfter the widget has been initialized, you can easily control the visibility through the methods `window.FB.CustomerChat.show()` and `window.FB.CustomerChat.hide()`

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer! Thank you.

Comment: This is true. However, it does not hide the greeting which will then stand alone. I haven't been able to find the docs on how I also hide this.